# How to re-create a svn repo out of a tarred backup on another machine

Tags: svn, version-control, backup

Sometime back, i took a tarred backup of full svn server directory.
Because at that time, in 2009, i couldn't find a good way to take a real backup.

The svn commands don't work on this as the repository url is not available on this machine.

```
svn log
svn: E200015: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://192.168.1.1/svn'
```

On searching, i could only find solutions for migration from a currently live svn repo to git, which i dont have.

My goal is to get a git repo out of this svn repo backup and i guess, I need to have a working svn repo as a first step.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

- Untar archive to some `REPOS_PATH`
- Check the repo with `svnadmin verify REPOS_PATH` (and fix it in case of problems with `svnadmin recover REPOS_PATH`)
- *OPTIONAL*: Upgrade the repository located at REPOS_PATH to the latest supported schema version (2009 is rather old) `svnadmin upgrade REPOS_PATH`

After it you have to have live SVN-repository, which can be accessed by `file:///` protocol (for git-svn or SubGit)